# How to subtract records from one array into other array and get new array of results?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$a1 = array("2"=>"35", "3"=>"37", "4"=>"43");
$a2 = array("4"=>"5", "2"=>"7", "3"=>"3");
```

Code used:

```
foreach($a1 as $key=>$val){
  print_r($a1[$key] - $a2[$key]);  
}
```

I want to subtract elements of second array from first array elements where keys are same and want to get results stored in new array new array

Please suggest how to archive this.

Thanks!

Comment: Loop `$result[$key] = $a1[$key] - $a2[$key];`

Comment: Writing code would be a good start. We're not here to do your job for you. Show what you've attempted, and we'll (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: I have updated question, please help in this case if its not right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($a1 as $key=>$val){
  $newArray[] = $a1[$key] - $a2[$key];  
}
```